# How to get a macOS VM to boot in safe mode?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware

Starting in safe mode on a Mac when you have access to the actual hardware is easy. You just press and hold the shift key while booting.

How can you boot into safe mode when running macOS (OSX) in a virtual machine?

Comment: I'm stuck in macOS Sierra installer (not enough space to install). Is there a way to get a command prompt from there so that I can boot in safe mode and erase some files ?

Answer (score 1):

Schmitty self answered in the Question. I edited the question and put his answer here as a Community Wiki.

**To start in safemode and verbose mode (Leave the -v off if you just want safe mode)**

```
sudo nvram boot-args="-x -v"
```

Then reboot

**To switch back to regular mode when you're done:**

```
sudo nvram boot-args=""
```

Then reboot

Answer (score 0):

It takes an adept hand, but you should be able to boot into safe mode with a virtual machine by preparing the console window, starting the VM, quickly clicking in the console window, and holding shift.

Depending on the reason you need in safe mode, you may be able to utilize the [on-disk macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) (Command-R) in the same way. Holding those keys immediately after starting the VM. This should work for Lion (10.7) and newer virtual machines.

From inside the recovery menu, you can browse the web with Safari; format or partition the disk; open a `Terminal.app` shell to remove files or otherwise modify the existing operating system, and install or re-install an operating system included in the recovery partition.

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated in this article:  https://isgb.otago.ac.nz/infosci/nigel.stanger/Wiki/wiki/Reboot%20VirtualBox%20macOS%20into%20recovery

`sudo nvram recovery-boot-mode=unused` then reboot

`nvram -d recovery-boot-mode` to disable it